# Limiting to a Specific Set of Characters in Regex Not Working

Tags: regex, string, validation

I need to validate a string to allow only a specific set of characters using regex. Unfortunately, I am stuck using regex only for the validation of these strings.

Anyways I need to limit a string to allow only the following characters:
a-z and A-Z and 0-9 and space and .,;:!=+-_

For this I have created the following expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.,;:!=+-_\s]*
```

I can't figure out why this expression is not working. The following test strings when I am using this are giving me the following results:

```
<test> Valid 
$<test> Invalid 
test Valid 
<test>asdf</test> Invalid
```

It appears the order of these special characters is being taken into account when really all I need to to limit the validation to a specific list of valid characters regardless of the order in the string.

Can anyone shed some light on why this may be allowing special characters such as '<>' but only in certain orders?

Comment: Which if the tests you mentione are not getting the desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use anchors and shild symbol `-`

`^[a-zA-Z0-9.,;:!=+\-_\s]*$`

Comment: Tested a bit further and haven't been able to determine any false validations. Thanks!